# Getting More Context Around PHPUnit Test Failures

Tags: php, phpunit, automated-tests

In PHPUnit, let's say I do this:

```
$this->assertTrue( $some_variable == "foo" );
```

When I run my tests with my code in a failing state, PHPUnit tells me: `Failed asserting that false is true.` Which is all fine and good, and I can usually track down WHY the test is failing. But...

I'm wondering if there is a way for PHPUnit to display more context to me when a test fails. For example, is it possible for PHPUnit to output something like: `Failed asserting that false is true. When your test ran $some_variable was equal to "bar"`. That would allow me to more quickly track down why the test failed.

I'd love it if I could see this extra context right in the CLI. Is there a setting I can apply to PHPUnit to make this happen?

Comment: You can use `TestListener` (deprecated), or new `TestHook`, **see** [**example for both on Github**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3390#issuecomment-1094838264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `assertTrue`

The `assertTrue` method has a second parameter, where you can specify a message that the assertion should throw when the assertion was negative:

```
$this->assertTrue($someVariable == "foo", '$someVariable should have been "foo"')
```

#### Using specialized assertion functions

PHPUnit offers a myriad of specialized assertions (for equality, identity, array elements and many more), which produce reasonable error messages. Have a look at the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html).

```
$this->assertEquals("foo", $someVariable);
```

Comment: The first method is not correct and I think the OP should be warned about it. The second method is the correct one and it should be stated more clearly.